# (C#, Connect four) - Coloring the button below

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, button

I am doing my programming examn and I am almost done with the game. I decided to go with connect four as it seemed to be a good chance to deal with some algrothicy features as I am not very used to that kind of coding.

The problem is simple: I need to color the buttons to create the effect of a falling brick. I wanted to do something like a big ass if statement to check if the coodinates == this then its this button to be colored. else if...

But thats gonna be pain and not very pretty. I was thinking if its possible by any chance to more or less take ALL buttons in the form and then take the x and y from the function generate a string and then find a button with that name

My buttons are label btxy
however I messed up the array first button is: 0,0
the name of first button is bt11 next one on x is bt12

I am from denmark so some variables is on Danish so is this function:

```
private void farv(int x, int y)
{
    x += 1;
    y += 1;
    MessageBox.Show("bt" + y.ToString() + x.ToString());
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c is Button)
        {
            if (c.Name == "bt" + x.ToString() + y.ToString())
            {
                if (playerValue == 1)
                {
                    c.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                }
                else if (playerValue == 10)
                {
                    c.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is the Coloring method.
I call it by this:

```
        temp = 0;
        while (temp < 6)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("While");
            farv(rowNr, temp);
            temp += 1;
        }
```

I cant really get it to working any way. Any suggestion? This turned out way harder than I expected, haha.

Comment: Rather than ask a question that sounds like "please do my homework for me"  its better to ask about a very specific issue your having.  VERY specific.  Like a couple of lines of code that you are having an issue with.

Comment: Are you sure playerValue always equals '1' or '10'? What part isn't working?

Comment: Is the problem that is "not working" that the UI doesn't update until the end, all of a sudden?

Comment: Also, have you thought about repositioning a single button to get the movement of the counter dropping?

Comment: Well. the whole homework is to make a whole connect four game and this is just a little part of the whole code. However I do see how it sounds like I am asking to make my homework I applozie for that. I might have been talking away from the problem I am sorry the problem was this:

I need to color the buttons to create the effect of a falling brick. I wanted to do something like a big ass if statement to check if the coodinates == this then its this button to be colored. else if...

Basicly make a falling effect when you press the row button :)

Comment: `like a big ass if statement` is quite possibly the funniest thing i've read in a week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what part "isn't working", but this works for me:

```
private void farv(int x, int y)
{
    var buttonName = string.Format("bt{0}{1}", x + 1, y + 1);

    var buttonControl = Controls.Find(buttonName, true).FirstOrDefault();

    if (buttonControl != null)
    {
        buttonControl.BackColor = GetColorForPlayer(playerValue);
    }
}

private Color GetColorForPlayer(int playerValue)
{
    Color defaultColor = SystemColors.Control;

    switch (playerValue)
    {
        case 1:
            return Color.Blue;
        case 10:
            return Color.Red;
        default:
            return defaultColor;
    }
}
```

Assuming you have a 6 x 6 board, you could use this like:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++)
    {
        farv(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: You did get it right it works like a charm. I see now I wrote away from my problem. I will try to be clearer next time.
Though I have a single problem when I click the row button I get:
that all buttons below get colored as they suppose to be. But the top one. bt11 - 0,0

Comment: Ignore the problem I am a tard. It works as it should